# Team Joining Issue in Bukkit Api

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

HiI'm making a bukkit plugin for creating teams. While using registerNewTeam() method I manage to create the team, but once I sing out and enter again the team is gone, I'm not getting any error. This is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if(sender instanceof Player) {
        //Player "ID"
        Player jugador = ((Player) sender).getPlayer();
        //Commands
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(comandos)) {
            sender.sendMessage(prefix + " Tu ping es de: "+ jugador.getPing());
            return true;
        }
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("create_fation")) {
            ScoreboardManager manager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
            Scoreboard board = manager.getNewScoreboard();
            Team team = board.registerNewTeam(args[0]);
            team.setPrefix("["+args[0]+"] ");
            team.setSuffix("0");
            team.setDisplayName(args[0]);
            team.addPlayer(jugador);
            sender.sendMessage(prefix + "Su faccion a sido creada exitosamente");
            return true;
        }
    }else {
        sender.sendMessage(prefix + " Solo los jugadores pueden usar comandos");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new ScoreBoard and a ScoreBoardManager every time a player enters and leaves.
Try making it so the scoreboard and is manager are created and all the same since the plugin is enabled.